# Magento2: Create orders grid replica and add custom columns

Tags: magento2, orders, api, order-grid, sales

I want to replicate the order grid, add custom columns in it and fetch that columns data from the API.

Comment: You mean, you want to create orders grid replica with additional custom columns and then want to fetch the same via API?

Comment: yes the same thing

Comment: Is there anything that you can help me

Comment: Yes. I have created a module for the same & it seems to be working fine. I'm preparing the answer for the same & then will post here.

Comment: okay please post the answer here

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps to create replica of orders grid.**

**Steps:**

1. Create a basic module Vendor_Module OR use your module & then rename the module name to the below files.
2. Create below file into the basic/your module.

**File 1: Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::order_grid" title="Order Grid" module="Vendor_Module" parent="Magento_Sales::sales" sortOrder="20" action="customgrid/order/grid" resource="Vendor_Module::order_grid"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**File 2: Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="customgrid" frontName="customgrid">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**File 3: Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Grid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container;

class Grid extends Container
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Module';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_order_grid';
        $this->_headerText = __('Order Grid');
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

**File 4: Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Grid/Container.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container as GridContainer;

class Container extends GridContainer
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Vendor_Module';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_order_grid';
        $this->_headerText = __('Order Grid');
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

**File 5: Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Grid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Grid extends Action
{
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Vendor_Module::order_grid');
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Vendor_Module::order_grid');
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Order Grid'));
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**File 6: Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/vendor_module_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Grid" name="custom_order_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**File 7: Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Grid/Grid.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;

class Grid extends Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Order ID'),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'type' => 'number',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'increment_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Order Increment ID'),
                'index' => 'increment_id',
            ]
        );

        // Add your custom columns here
        $this->addColumn(
            'custom_column',
            [
                'header' => __('Custom Column'),
                'index' => 'custom_column',
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

In the above grid columns file, you will have to add the required columns & your custom/additional columns.

**Now run necessary commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After completing the above steps, you should be able to see your custom orders grid in the admin panel under Sales > Order Grid. Adjust the code as needed based on your specific requirements.

Keep in mind that this is a basic example, and you may need to customize it further based on your specific use case and requirements.

Thankyou !!

Comment: I successfully created the replica, but I want to add custom columns in the ui and from the third party API fetch the data from that custom columns and update it accordingly

Comment: I think now you can create a API function in helper or other place to fetch the data and then connect that function into the 7th file _prepareColumns function.

Comment: okay, can you please also provide that code as well